# "the following arguments are required: action" error on Python

Tags: python, ethernet

I am beginner for the Python so sorry this basic question. (And sorry for my English)
I try to use this [github code](https://github.com/devkid/profinet) blocks for Profinet communication. If i call the main.py this way:

```
python main.py -i discover
```

Than I have a this error:

```
usage: main.py [-h] -i INTERFACE
               {discover,get-param,set-param,read,read-inm0-filter,read-inm0,read-inm1,write-inm1}
               [target] [param] [value] [additional1] [additional2]
main.py: error: the following arguments are required: action
```

And than I try to use this line:

```
python server.py -i eth0
```

And I have this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 20, in <module>
    s = ethernet_socket(args.i, 0x8892)
  File "/home/name/Documents/profinet-master/util.py", line 25, in ethernet_socket
    s = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 144, in __init__
    _socket.socket.__init__(self, family, type, proto, fileno)
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
```

And that is the etherneth_socket:

```
def ethernet_socket(interface, ethertype):
    s = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW)
    s.bind((interface, ethertype))
    return s
```

How can I use this code or how can I call this python code. Please help me thank you.

Comment: Shouldn't you call it as `python main.py -i eth0 discover` for discovery, at least based on the help screen you've posted? `-i INTERFACE` seems to be the mandatory argument pair, followed by a mandatory action (discover, get-param, set-param...).

Comment: Creating raw sockets is a privileged operation, since they could be used to bypass security-related restrictions on normal sockets.  You'll need to run this program with `sudo`.

Comment: @jasonharper i have a new error with sudo : debug and print ("MAC address:" +  mac2s(eth.src) )
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
and that is include line100 in dcp.py

Comment: @CKocar That sounds like a new question.

Comment: No. i just try to with "sudo" command